# Nautilus ugly with custom GTK themes

Tags: gnome3, nautilus, theme, gtk3

Nautilus, for some reason, becomes very ugly when using custom GTK+ themes. I can't figure out why. There are only a few ones GTK+ themes work properly with Nautilus.

[image]

How do I fix this? Is this a Nautilus issue?

Here's a list of data that I think might be relevant:

- I'm using GNOME 3 on ArchLinux
- Icon themes aren't working under any account but root for Nautilus (works for other applications)
- Window themes are being ignored by Nautilus, Gnome Tweak Tool and System Monitor
- System restart, GNOME restart or Nautilus restart does not fix anything
- Some themes work (Zukitwo and Numix)

Comment: What counts as "very ugly"? I mean, which part(s) of the above screenshot do you need help removing/fixing/...?

Comment: Basically everything. The colours are wrong, there us no window borders, the top control bar has the buttons styled wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes that make Nautilus look ugly are not updated to support that new header bar widget that came with GTK 3.10

some examples of themes that don't work and some that do work:
[image: Clearlooks-phenix theme under GTK 3.12]
[image: Windows 8 theme under GTK 3.12]
[image: Numix theme under GTK 3.12]
[image: Default Adwaita theme]

Answer (score -3):

Theme must be under `/usr/share/themes`
if your theme in `~/.themes`, root apps will not use it.

Comment: My theme is in there.